# Can you log or block automatic command line actions?

Tags: command-line

In the past week, I have been seeing the command line pop and close every 10-15 minutes. Very concerned about some type of malware or even a program causing it that I can remove.

I have read much here about logging output from the command line but is it possible to log activity or even block the command line from working/.

Answer (score 0):

you can use CurrPorts,This software allows you to see processes that use the network and to kill processes

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html